# Adding multiple items to listBox - only some work

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-forms-designer

Currently covering GUI's, I want to write a program that takes two integers and puts them and their product in a `listBox`. Currently I have a `textBox` for each integer, and a button that adds them to the `listBox`. There is then a third button that calculates the product and adds it to the `listBox`. The first two buttons work - but the third one does not - clicking the button doesn't do anything. Routing that button to a different `listBox` doesn't fix the error. My current code is below:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Int1;
        Int1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add(Int1);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Int2;
        Int2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add(Int2);
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Product;
        Product = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) * int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add(Product);
    }
```

I have also tried separately parsing `textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text` when finding Product, to no avail.

EDIT: `this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);` was missing from the code. It works now.

Comment: what happens when you debug the code? Are you sure you are reaching button3_click event handler?

Comment: I don't seem to be reaching it.  I put a breakpoint at button2_click and then stepped into each step, but when it hit button3_Click the yellow debugging arrow disappears, and it sent me to the form.

Comment: I realized where I went wrong - somehow VisualStudio wasn't giving me the standard error that I had an event handler in place without the corresponding line in the designer tab (namely `this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);` was somehow missing. 

Thank you, I'm sorry if this ended up being a pointless time sap.

Comment: REB1959: it's perfectly appropriate, and encouraged to answer you own question, if you discover the answer.  So you could post what you discovered as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click); was missing from the code. It works now.